# How can we train a toddler that shares a room with siblings to sleep without disturbing the others?

Tags: siblings, sleep

My four children share one room.  My first three children I sleep trained by using the cry it out method (I know this is controversial on this site but it worked for me).

We did sleep train the fourth child the same way in the guest room and that worked great.

She is now 22 months old and she has been constantly calling us for her blankets at bed time and then sometimes during the night.  We don't want to use the cry it out method as it will wake up her siblings, but we must get her to sleep on her own and get her own blankets.  I would appreciate some suggestions of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got a much bigger blanket an put her in a big girl bed, explaining to her that now that she is a big girl she takes care of herself at night.  It worked.

Answer (score 4):

Time for a lesson in independence.

Are the blankets where she can reach them? or are they on her bed but she's just beeing needy? How long as this been going on?

Based on the info that you gave, I would suggest:

- Keeping the blankies where she can get them.
- When she hollers for it, come in the room and turn the light on. yes it will wake everyone up, but there's a point.
- Direct her, curtly, to get out of bed and get her blanket.

> "get out of bed. you know where the blankets are, go over there and get one. Good. Take it over to your bed, spread it out.

let her start and try for a bit *then* help as needed. then when she's back in bed and comfy, here's the lesson.

> "See what you did? You wanted your blanket and there it is, you did it yourself. You know where your blankets are and you can get them yourself. You don't need me for that because it wakes everyone up. Ok? Mwa. Ganight.

The whole reason for being curt is it's a simple way to express your displeasure without much longevity. a couple nights of that should make the point.

[edit] you may wind up with a bunch of blankets to fold up every day, but that's a small price for you to pay for her sense of independence and the well-being of the others.